# create a content type managed property via powershell

Tags: 2010, search, powershell

Regarding this blog post, its very easy to do visually. But for easy deployment on other environments I would like to do this in a powershell script.

http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html

I have found this information here:
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/05/26/creating-enterprise-search-metadata-property-mappings-with-powershell.aspx

But its very unclear how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the blogpost you mention from Corey Roth explains it all. What did you try already and what are the successes and failures?